# MIPS beginner: count amount of 0s in array

Tags: arrays, mips, counting

Can someone help me with my MIPS code? I don't get why it doesn't work. I want to count the amount of zeroes in my array. Am I not traversing my array correctly?

```
       .data
array:      .word 20, 0, 3, 0, 0, -4, 0, -30, 120, 0, 0 # 
array of integers
array_size: .word 11 # number of elements in array

        .text
        .globl main
main:
  la $t0, array      # array[0]'s address
  lw $t1, array_size # array_size
  li $t2, 0          # amount of zeroes = 0
  li $t3, 0          # i = 0

Lbegin:
  bge $t3, $1, Ldone # if(i >= array_size) goto Ldone 

  # array[i]  
  sll $t4, $t3, 2    # i x 4 (aka offset)
  add $t4, $t4, $t0  # array[0 + i]'s address
  lw  $t5, 0($t4)    # retrieve value array[i]

  beqz $t5, Lequal_zero # if(array[i] == 0) goto Lequal_zero
  b Li_increment        # goto i++

Lequal_zero:
  addi $t2, $t2, 1      # amount of zeroes + 1

Li_increment:
  addi $t3, $t3, 1      # i++
  b Lbegin              # loop again

Ldone:
  li $v0, 1
  move $a0, $t2
  syscall

  jr $ra
```

Comment: `bge $t3, $1, Ldone` <-- `$1` and `$t1` are different registers.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I'm so blind. It works now!